# Joomla plugin manager missing options, how do I start trouble shooting this?

Tags: joomla

There are no options displayed when I'm looking at a plugin with the plugin manager. Where there should be a menu for basic and advance options is just white space. How can I start trouble shooting this problem? Other installed extensions work fine and hours of searching about plugin options make me think this is a peculiar error. This is what my menu looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2S4K.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you are using is not written for Joomla 1.6, the XML manifest needs to be updated at the very least. The plugin itself may also need to be rewritten. I would start withe the XML file first, you can find details on the changes that need to be made here - http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/112-upgrading-a-plugin-to-joomla-16.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Instead of just ignoring 1.5 plugins I can see about trying to tinker with them.

Comment: Most 1.5 extensions that are MVC and well coded should not be too hard to update. In many cases the differences are minor.